# How to skip a gradle task under some cases, which introduced by the bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, docker

I use the gradle plugin [bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) to integrate docker with gradle. I create some tasks in the build.gradle file:

```
    task copyJar(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn build

    from project.file("$project.buildDir/libs/" << jarName)
    into project.file("$project.buildDir/docker")
}

task createDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
    dependsOn copyJar

    // Generate Dockerfile
}

task buildDockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    dependsOn createDockerfile

    inputDir = createDockerfile.destFile.parentFile
    tag = 'example.com/' << jar.baseName
    if (project.hasProperty('imageTag')) {
        tag += ':' << imageTag
    }
}
task pushDockerImage(type: DockerPushImage) {
    dependsOn buildDockerImage
    conventionMapping.imageName = { 'example.com/' + jar.baseName }
    if (project.hasProperty('imageTag')) {
        conventionMapping.tag = { imageTag }
    }
}
```

What I want is when I run `gradle pushDockerImage`, if there is no change in the source code this task could be skipped. However, now each time I run the `gradle pushDockerImage`, it will be executed and last a long time to push the image to the docker registry.

I also run `gradle --info pushDockerImage` two times, the second time gradle shows the following infomation:

```
Skipping task ':core/sample:buildDockerImage' as task onlyIf is false.
:core/sample:buildDockerImage SKIPPED
:core/sample:buildDockerImage (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took     1.765 secs.
:core/sample:pushDockerImage (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:core/sample:pushDockerImage
Executing task ':core/sample:pushDockerImage' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
    Task has not declared any outputs.
```

So here `buildDockerImage` is skipped, but `pushDockerImage` is not. How can I also skip it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare created image on task copyJar as input to pushDockerImage task. 
Something like:

```
task pushDockerImage(type: DockerPushImage) {
    dependsOn buildDockerImage
    inputs.file project.file("$project.buildDir/docker")
    ...
```

See paragraph 17.9 on gradle user guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html for details

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
dockerBuildImage {
    images = ["packagerepository.com/username/artefactName:${version}"]
}
```

obviously put your own tag in place of what are effectively placeholders for your tag name